# Use selected object instead of generating new ones on particles system

Tags: particles

I'm trying to animate a group of butterflies resting on a skull, which all fly away together at a certain frame. For the starting butterfly, I've set up two shape keys, one with closed wings and one with raised wings, and I've made them cyclic.

For the flight of the butterflies as a group, I duplicated the butterfly several times, placed them all in a collection, and positioned them above the skull in the initial position where I want them. Then I tried to animate them using the particle system, using the skull as the emitter, and under 'render as,' I chose the butterfly collection. It took me a while to play with the settings, but in the end, I managed to put together a flight that seemed satisfying to me.

The problem is how the animation starts. The simulator, when it starts, **instead of directly animating the butterflies within the collection positioned on the skull, generates new butterflies, while those in the collection remain still where they are. Instead, I would like the simulator, instead of generating new butterflies and animating them, simply to take the butterflies from the collection and animate those, without creating new ones**.

Is there a way to do this? The only way that comes to my mind, with my current limited knowledge, would be to bake the animation for each frame, then move the keyframes, delete the initial ones I don't want, and then reposition the butterflies at frame 1, one by one, where I want them to be, but it's a bit of a lengthy process that I wouldn't want to repeat since I've already positioned them.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: did you try to set start and end frame on the same frame (your "certain frame") in your particle settings? if this doesn't help, pls provide blend file. thx.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if a PS can do this, although there are many options of Render that might accomplish this.   Here are some ideas:

[brainstorming] ... perhaps some use of an (hidden) Explode object that is a duplicate of your skull, where the bflys are child objects....

Here's one tested idea... Rigid Body physics:

I placed some bfly objects (here represented by cones), on the surface of a sphere, and added RB physics to each (you should be able to add to one and then ctrl-C Copy Modifiers for the others?).  I added keyframes to the Dynamic property for the keyframe where they should start flying away.

[image]

I disabled Gravity for the scene's Rigid Body World, although this will disable for all other objects with RB physics (bad side effect!).

[image]

I then added a Force with *sufficient strength* (I'd experiment on how fast these should fly away), to the center of the skull.

[image]

As as cute and simple wing-flapping, I animated a Simple Deform modifier, and added a Sine modifier.   You'd probably want to animate the wing-vertices of your bfly.

[image]

My example: [image]

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the detailed answer. This looks like an intresting approach and im gonna try that. The way I have solved it until now was baking the particles animation into keyframe using a free addon (Cake particles 2.0) and then for frame one I used a pyton script to place all generated butterflies on the surface of the skull. It works ok, but it still needs lots of finetuning for the placement, and its not very flexible to edit. I think your approach sound better, Im gonna give it a try. Thanks again.